# Need help finding the projection of a vector onto a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

(a) Find the projection of the vector $\vec b=(2,1,0,1)$ onto the subspace $V$ consisting of all vectors of the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ such that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0$.

(b) What is the distance from the vector $\vec b$ to the subspace $V$?

Formulas needed: $\|\vec u-\vec v\|=$ distance

${\rm proj}_{\vec v}\vec u=\frac{\langle \vec u,\vec v\rangle}{\|\vec v\|^2}\vec v$.

Comment: If you have those formulas, then it should be possible to solve the question using the equation for a (hyper)plane. Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ is a basis for a subspace $S$ of $\Bbb R^n$, then the
**projection matrix** of $S$ is
$$
P=A\left(A^\top A\right)^{-1} A^\top
$$
where
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & v_2 & \dotsb & v_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In our case, the columns of
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0  & 0 \\
0  & 1  & 0 \\
0  & 0  & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
form a basis for the subspace $S$ of $\Bbb R^4$ described by the equation
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0
$$
One checks that
$$
P = \frac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
3  & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 3  & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 3  & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence the projection of $\vec b$ onto $S$ is
$$                                                                                                                                                                                             
P \vec b =                                                                                                                                                                                           
 \frac{1}{4}                                                                                                                                                                                   
\begin{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                
3  & -1 & -1 & -1 \\                                                                                                                                                                           
-1 & 3  & -1 & -1 \\                                                                                                                                                                           
-1 & -1 & 3  & -1 \\                                                                                                                                                                           
-1 & -1 & -1 & 3                                                                                                                                                                               
\end{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                  
\begin{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                
2\\1\\0\\1                                                                                                                                                                                     
\end{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                  
=                                                                                                                                                                                              
\begin{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                
1\\0\\-1\\0                                                                                                                                                                                    
\end{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                                                                  
$$
The distance from $\vec b$ to $S$ is then given by $\lVert\vec b-P\vec b\rVert$. Can you compute this distance?

An advantage to this strategy is that it is quite algorithmic. If you are interested in the derivation of the formula for the projection matrix $P$, check out [this note](http://faculty.uml.edu/dklain/projections.pdf).

Comment: I'm a little confused, the way that David answered it gives me a different type of answer than yours. Which one is correct D:

Comment: the answer i got when i solved David's way is (3/2,1/2,-3/2,-1/2) for part a and for part b got a distance of (5)^(1/2)

Comment: That distance would be 2 right?

Comment: So did i do something wrong when i solved it David's way?

Comment: You are correct that the distance is $2$. Try reworking the numbers with David's solution.

Comment: I edited the post to have my attempt at a solution, maybe you can find where i went wrong, if not then that's totally fine i'll keep working with it, thanks a lot for the help man, i really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Nice catch! Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to do this, here is my favourite.

First find a basis for $V$.  And to make it as easy as possible, find a basis consisting of *orthogonal* vectors.  In this case it's not too hard by trial and error, say
$$\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}
  \v v_1=(1,-1,0,0)\ ,\quad \v v_2=(0,0,1,-1)\ ,\quad \v v_3=(1,1,-1,-1)\ .$$
Then
$$\def\proj{{\rm proj}}
  \proj_V\v b=\proj_{\v v_1}\v b+\proj_{\v v_2}\v b+\proj_{\v v_3}\v b\ ,
  \tag{$*$}$$
and each term can be calculated from your projection formula.

Then find the distance between $\v b$ and the projection by using your distance formula.

**Note** that $(*)$ is true because $\v v_1,\v v_2$ and $\v v_3$ are mutually orthogonal - it will not give the correct answer for just any old basis.

Answer (score 1):

The vector $\vec w = \frac{1}{2} (1,1,1,1)$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $V$. The projection of $\vec b$ onto $\vec w$ is the vector $2 \vec w = (1,1,1,1)$. Thus, the vector $\vec b - 2\vec w = (1,0,-1,0)$ is the orthogonal projection of $\vec b$ onto $V$. Notice, that $\vec b = (2,1,0,1) = (1,1,1,1) + (1,0,-1,0)$ is the decomposition of $\vec b$ as a sum of two orthogonal vectors, one in $V$ and one orthogonal to $V$. The distance of $\vec b$ to $V$ is $\|2 \vec w\| = 2$.